# AlarmManager Kotlin

Tags: kotlin, alarmmanager

i am doing a school project,
i receive a bunch of data set, and each object has a time stamp.

i just want to set a simple alarm manager and push a notification on scheduled time for each object.
i loop the data set and foreach object call the setAlarm function.
for now i just pass the object DateTime  as string.

```
    private fun setAlaram(){
/// this just converts the time from GMT +0 into GMT +1
/// my API always returns time in GMT +0
        val time = Companion.convertToTimezoneCET("2020-01-01T21:08:00.000Z")
        val calender = Calendar.getInstance(Locale.getDefault())
        Log.v("ALARM", "ALARMTIME: ${time.hour}:${time.minute}")
        calender.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, time.hour)
        calender.set(Calendar.MINUTE, time.minute)
        calender.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0)
        calender.set(Calendar.MILLISECOND,0)

        noti(calender)
    }

    private fun noti(c: Calendar){
        val alarmManager = context!!.getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE) as AlarmManager
        val requestCode = 100
        var pendingIntent: PendingIntent? = null

        val sendIntent = Intent(context, AlarmReceiver::class.java)
        sendIntent.putExtra("EXTRA_PESAN", "EXTRA MESSAGE")

        pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, requestCode, sendIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT)
        alarmManager.setExact(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, c.timeInMillis, pendingIntent)
        //ClearAlarms
//         alarmManager.cancel(pendingIntent)

    }
```

And this is my AlarmReceiver

```
class AlarmReceiver : BroadcastReceiver() {
    override fun onReceive(context: Context?, intent: Intent?) {
        val builder = NotificationCompat.Builder(context!!)
            .setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher)
            .setContentText(context.getString(R.string.alarmMessage))
            .setContentTitle(context.getString(R.string.app_name))
            .setPriority(NotificationCompat.PRIORITY_HIGH)
            .build()

        val notiManager = context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE) as NotificationManager
        notiManager.notify(0, builder)
    }
}
```

My code is not working! notifications are not received.

Comment: and the question is?

Comment: The above code is not working?? notifications are not send on set time!